# Installing Windows 7 on pre-existing Ubuntu 12.04 for Dual-Boot FAQ?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

I just wanted to ask a few questions before I completely destroy my system.

My system currently has Ubuntu12.04 on it, I have 100GB of unallocated space where the plan is to install a fresh copy of Windows 7 for Dual-Boot purposes.

1. How can I be sure that when I re-boot into the windows CD, the correct partition is chosen? And Ubuntu partition is safe/ wont be overwritten?
2. Would this be the correct way of doing it?:

   - Create a free partition with GParted
   - Install Windows and Reboot into UbuntuCD live session
   - Install and Run Boot-Repair
   - Boot Again, Grub will display Windows and Ubuntu.

It seems a little straight forward, am I missing something? What are the common mistakes people make and is there anything I should watch out for?

Also after reading around, I find there is more than one way of achieving this.

I read somewhere that you can also take the Windows ISO and put it into the boot folder? Then somehow configuring GRUB options...

Any suggestions and advice is strongly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6317/65969)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Windows7 is a little smarted than XP, as it should not modify the Linux partitions. However, by security, you should `always backup your Ubuntu documents before installing Windows.`

**2.** Your procedure seems ok. Don't forget to `format the free partition in NTFS` via gParted, so that WIndows can easily detect it.