# How to install windows 7 in an extended partition

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, lvm

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 a few days back. As I was in a hurry I clicked on the LVM option. Now when i open GParted in the live cd, it shows that the SDA5 partition has only 16 mb of free space. So is there a way to install windows 7 without having to re install Ubuntu as i have a really slow internet connection and it takes like 2 hours to download just the language packs. If not is there a way to backup all the files like language packs and packages, updates etc. to an external HDD ?

Comment: try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary,

a. Install the Windows OS pointing to the extended partition (formatted for Windows used) 
b. Configure either OS' boot loader (run boot repair)
c. Enjoy (Grub will now give you 2 OS options to load upon boot)

Regardless of what I said, you can see tons of tutorials on how to do this, either Ubuntu first or Windows first.

Here is an example of one:
[Installing Windows 7 on pre-existing Ubuntu 12.04 for Dual-Boot FAQ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170927/installing-windows-7-on-pre-existing-ubuntu-12-04-for-dual-boot-faq)